# Hi, I'm trying to instal Nuget packagebut the following appear

Tags: visual-studio, nuget

This is the result, I tried many packages but all say the same.
I'm using Visual Studio 2019

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Could not install package 'SQLitePCLRaw.core 2.0.4'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'native,Version=v0.0', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.

As I'm new in this field I don't understand what it means,
Thanks for your help

Comment: You have some misunderstandings. This is a c# nuget package and you cannnot install it with c++ project. You should create a c# project and then you can install this nuget package.

Comment: Any update about this issue?  If you still have any issue about this issue, please feel free to let us know. And if the answer helps, please do not forget to accept it. And if you already have an answer about your issue, you could add the answer here.

Comment: Any update about this issue? If you still have any issue about this issue, please feel free to let us know. And if the answer helps, please do not forget to accept it. And if you already have an answer about your issue, you could add the answer here.

Answer (score 0):

You can see that this nuget package depends on the `.net` which means  that it is used for **C#** projects.

[image]

From your description, you have installed this package on a **C++** project. So the error happens.

I have a small test: install this package in **C++** project which proves the root cause of the issue.

[image]

**Suggestion**

**You should create a **C#** project and then you can install this nuget package on that.**